# SocketIO authorization function not working on local

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am facing an socketio authorization function in my local nodejs application. On my server the authorization function works just fine. Its just that on my local its not working. Here is the code

```
var FeedsMain = global.FeedsMain = {}
, colors = require('./colors')
, conf = FeedsMain.conf = require('./conf').config
, SITE_SECRET = conf.app.secret
, zerorpc = require('zerorpc')
, rpcClient = new zerorpc.Client()
, feeds = require('socket.io').listen(conf.app.port)
, services = require('./lib/services')
, feedsService = services.getFeedsService()
, authService = services.getAuthService()
, profileVisitorsService = services.getProfileVisitorsService()
, searchService = services.getSearchService()
, usersService = services.getUserService()
, temptingEventsDistributionService = services.getTemptingEventsDistributionService()
, likesService = services.getLikesService()
, commentsService = services.getCommentsService()
, emitter = require('./lib/events').eventAPI
, eventAPI = require('./lib/events').eventAPI
, dataStore = require('./lib/events').store
, _ = require('lodash')
, cookie = require('cookie')
, authMap = {}
;

require('./clientResources').add(feeds);

rpcClient.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:4242');

rpcClient.on('error', function(error) {
    console.error('RPC client error:', error);
});

feeds.set('log level', 1);

feeds.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, accept) {
  console.log('authorization function run');
    if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
    handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
    var dg_01 = handshakeData.cookie['dg_01']
    ;
    if(dg_01) {
      rpcClient.invoke('getUser', dg_01, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
          return accept('Unauthorized', false);
        }
        handshakeData.userId = user._id;
        handshakeData.user = user;
        handshakeData.sessionId = dg_01;
        setSessionId(user._id, dg_01);
        return accept(null, true);
      });
    }
    else {
      console.log('Invalid session id: %s'.red, dg_01);
      return accept('Invalid Session!', false);
    }
  } else {
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  }
});
console.log('authorization method over');
```

As you would notice, all the variables are initialized ok. The feeds variable which is basically socket io initialization starts on port 4000. When I do localhost:4000, I get welcome to socket.io.

However the authorization function doesn't run. I tried inserting a console.log('authorization function started') but it doesn't happen. However in the console I see authorization method over, which means that the authorization function was skipped completely.

On my server everything works ok where I see messages like session set etc. that originate from authorization function. On my local it just doesn't seem to work.

Anyone has a clue what could be the case.